# pyGTK : pack and unpack

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

Can I use pack once the main loop has been showed, or should I use something else to add /remove widgets to /from a vbox afterwards ?

I have this `gtk.Window()` that contains a `vbox`, where a `menu`, a `treeview` and a `button` are `pack`ed. At the push of this button, I want to display an image in a new container inside this window / vbox, and ideally, close said container at will.

(think image viewer with a file list, you click on an image file and a pane opens displaying it, if you click on another image file the new image is displayed in place of the old, and you can close the image pane)

My question is : How do you do that ? My trials so far led me to believe that once the `vbox` has been `show()`'d, you cant `pack` anything else into it..?
Has the "image" container have to exist prior to being displayed...?

What is the proper process to do this, in witch direction of the GTK manual should I look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GTK+ all widgets are hidden by default (which I think was a stupid design decision, but oh well). You usually call `show_all()` on a window, so indirectly show all widgets contained in it *by the time of the call*. If you add (pack, whatever) a widget later, don't forget to `show()` it manually.